# Show that $f'_+(a)=f'(a+)$ if both quantities exist.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Show that $f'_+(a)=f'(a+)$ if both quantities exist.  I'm not really sure where to start, any help is appreciated.

I came up with this:

If $f'(a^+)$ exists, then by definition $f'(a+) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a^+)} {x-a^+}$. If $f'_+(a)$ exists, then by definition $f'_+(a) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)} {x-a}$. Since f is only guaranteed to be defined on $[a,x)$ for some x in $D_f$, we can rewrite this as $f'_+(a) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a^+)} {x-a^+}$ and thus $f'_+(a) = f'(a^+)$.

Does this look ok?

Comment: You can start with the definitions of the terms. Did you write out what everything means?

Comment: I've edited with a proof based of the definitions, does it look acceptable?

Comment: You should have $f'(a+) = \lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t>a$ then we have $$\frac{f(a)-f(t)}{t-a} =f'(\xi)$$ where $a<\xi < t$ by Lagrange Theorem. Now letting $t\to a$ we obtain $$f'_+ (a) =f'(a+).$$

Comment: This is usually called the mean value theorem, at least in US schools. It is of course a special case of the Lagrange remainder theorem in the theory of Taylor polynomials, so I see where you are coming from in calling it the Lagrange theorem.

Comment: For example here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Lagrange's_Mean_Value_Theorem